# Google Maps API V3 zoom in/out with a button outside the map itself

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a company website of an acquaintance of mine. The company has 7 offices spread all over the country. He has asked me to create a page listing these offices (with contact info, picture, etc.), and add a Google map to it with multiple markers that indicate the offices.

I've done so, but seeing as the zoom-level (a complete country) isn't really detailed, I was thinking about making the map zoom in to specific markers/offices when clicking on the office in the aforementioned list.

I however have no idea if there's a way to perform actions inside the map, from outside the map. Does anybody know?

The website is not live yet, but as an example, you can take a look at this link: http://www.inter-psy.nl/contact/contactgegevens
What I'd like to do is (for example) make the colored block/header perform a map zoom-in to a specific marker when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make the `map`-variable globally accessible, then you may perform any action on the map from anywhere in the page(e.g. `map.setCenter()` to center the map at a specific location or `map.setZoom()` to set the zoom-level)

To make the variable globally accessible remove the **`var`**-keyword when creating the map